# LOF vs k-NN in data with varying density

Tags: anomaly-detection

When the dataset is comprised of regions of varying densities, which technique is more effective for outlier detection Localised Outlier Factor(LoF) or K-Nearest neighbors (KNN)

Answer (score 0):

Localised Outlier Factor(LoF) would be better for groups with varying densities. Pls check the formula for LOF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).